# How do you use an extended dojo.dnd.Source class in markup?

Tags: dojo

The below XHTML, a vast simplification of the real app, results in Firebug reporting "Could not load class 'my.dojo.dnd.Source":

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      @import url("http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.6/dojo/resources/dojo.css");
      @import url("http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.6/dojo/resources/dnd.css");
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      dojo.require("dojo.dnd.Source");
    </script>
    <script>
    // <![CDATA[
      dojo.ready(function()
      {
        dojo.provide("my.dojo.dnd.Source");
        dojo.declare("my.dojo.dnd.Source", dojo.dnd.Source,
        {
          markupFactory: function(params, node)
          {
            params._skipStartup = true;
            return new my.dojo.dnd.Source(node, params);
          }
        });
      });
    // ]]>
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul dojoType="my.dojo.dnd.Source">
        <li class="dojoDndItem">foo</li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

In the real app, the extension does something useful, of course. Also, in the real app, the `ul` is actually a `table` whose contents may be repeatedly re-rendered by Ajax calls based on user action. For this post, I tried to strip the problem down to its bare essentials.

I'm not sure about the need for the `markupFactory` override, but I saw it used in other examples and thought it might be necessary. The same error message is reported without it.

My suspicion is that somebody somewhere is trying to load the extended class before the `dojo.declare` takes effect. If I do the `dojo.provide` and `dojo.declare` outside of the `dojo.ready`, I get the messages `dojo.dnd is undefined` and `_43.clsInfo.cls.prototype is undefined`, presumably because the `dojo.require` is asynchronous.

If instead of saying `<ul dojoType="my.dojo.dnd.Source">` I say `<ul dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source">` and use `setAttribute` to set `dojoType` in the `onReady` function, the error message goes away. I don't know if the code actually becomes functional or not. Regardless, this wouldn't really be an acceptable solution because of the Ajax re-rendering, as I mentioned above.

Perhaps I am missing something really simple here. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the effect I wanted by doing the following:

- Setting parseOnLoad to false instead of true.
- Defining a 'reparse' function that set the new dojoType on the appropriate DOM nodes and reparsing the appropriate DOM subtree (using dojo.parser.parse).
- Calling reparse in the dojo.ready function and after every Ajax re-render.

See, it **was** simple.